# Live file upload

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, file-upload

I am working on a jQuery live file upload.

There is a form in my application with a file field. when the user selects a file, then I need to upload it using the AJAX file upload method. Then later when user submit on the "Submit" then the real file upload will take place .

Using the following, my AJAX file upload is going perfectly. But the problem is that after the file upload, the file field's value will get cleared.

```
var url = $('#site').val()
url = url + "/ajax/addTmpImg";

var id = 'my_file';

alert($('#' + id).val()); // THIS WILL SHOW FILE FIELD VALUE

$.ajaxFileUpload({
    url: url,
    secureuri: false,
    fileElementId: id,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'type': file_name,
        'name': file_name
    },
    success: function (data, status) {
        alert($('#' + id).val()); // THIS WILL RETURN EMPTY
    },
    error: function (data, status, e) {
        alert(status);
    }
});
```

Before the file upload, this will alert the file field's value and after the file upload, doing the same will show nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define a global variable and assign the value `$('#'+id).val()` to that variable.

Like this:

```
var someVar = $('#'+id).val();
```

You can access that variable later.

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = $('#site').val();
url = url + "/ajax/addTmpImg";

var id = 'my_file';
var val = $('#' + id).val();

alert(val); // THIS WILL SHOW FILE FIELD VALUE

$.ajaxFileUpload({
    url: url,
    secureuri: false,
    fileElementId: id,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {

        'type': file_name,
        'name': file_name
    },
    success: function (data, status) {


        alert(val); // THIS WILL SHOW FILE FIELD VALUE
    },
    error: function (data, status, e) {
        alert(status);


    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and my problem is ajax file upload will be fine and the file field's value get cleared after file upload. ie, cant submit the file again for upload ( it will get empty )